# Linux Live USB MD5 checksum integrity check failed for 5 files, are these files relevant?

Tags: linux-mint, live-usb, checksum

When running manually the MD5 checksum integrity check from a USB Live Boot medium (Linux Mint 19), the command line shows "failed" for these 5 files:

```
grub.cfg   
loopback.cfg
chain.c32
isolinux.cfg
vesamenu.c32
```

What could be the cause, the usb creator tool used? Should I re-write the ISO with another tool? I used Yumi and added the "persistent" feature.

Comment: Those files are 'only' used during the boot process. How did you create the liveUSB drive? Which tool did you use? From where did you get the iso file? It is possible that your tool to create the live drive made th modifications, but I cannot be sure, when I don't know the details.

Comment: hi @sudodus, as written in my question, the tool for creating the Live USB is called YUMI. And I enabled the persistent feature, used MBR mode and Fat32. The ISO was 100% correct I checked its hash checksums and corresponding signatures. From the official download website "linuxmint.com".  ---Can you please clarify if those 5 files *CAN* be malicious. Or is it Ok that they sometimes fail the MD5 check?

Answer (score 2):

When the iso file is correct, it must be the tool YUMI, that modified (or replaced) those files.
-  And since you made a **persistent** live drive, some of the files **must** be modified.

- At least the `cfg` files, where persistent is configured by the boot option 'persistent` must be modified. They are text files, easy for you to check.
- The `c32` files belong to the syslinux bootloader and it is not clear to me why they have to be modified, but probably in order to match YUMI's set of syslinux files . YUMI is a well-known tool, and I think it is safe to use it, if you downloaded it from YUMI's own web site,

  [www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

---

- Other tools work in different ways, and may not modify the `c32` files. I know that the following tools are reliable, and they can create a **partition** for persistence, so that the whole drive can be used.

  - [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) in Windows
  - [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu and Debian and Linux distros that are developed from those distros. The boot system of Linux Mint is similar to Ubuntu's boot system, so mkusb (mkusb-dus) works with Linux Mint iso files.